# Facebook friends dialog without request

Tags: facebook

Does the Facebook developers API provide simple friends select dialog that won't send any request to Facebook?

I just want to give the user the possibility to select multiple friends from the list and get those friends' ID's.

I found something like this:
https://github.com/mbrevoort/jquery-facebook-multi-friend-selector
but I am surprised that I have to use external plugins.

Comment: Why does this surprise you? How would you get the users friends list without making a call to Facebook?

Comment: you can get the friend ids, but to you might have to use a custom UI if you don't actually want to send a request.

Comment: I expect that:
Friends select dialog will be displayed
and user will be able to select friends
and I get those friends ID's
but after that, no request will be send to facebook (like: application invitation)

Facebook provides only something like this:
`FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
          message: 'My Great Request'
        }, requestCallback);`
which always send application requests to selected friends.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just ran into exactly the same problem and it also shocked me that there's no plugin provided by Facebook.

Earlier you could have used fb:friend-selector from FBML but currently [fb:friend-selector](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/friend-selector/) is deprecated (and thus disabled in new apps) and soon will be completely removed.

Fortunately, there is a choice of some external plugins:

- [These Days Facebook Friend Selector](http://labs.thesedays.com/blog/2011/06/20/the-missing-facebook-interface-component-for-friend-selection/) from These Days Labs
- [Friends selection custom component](http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/12/24/facebook-friends-selection-custom-component/) by Mahmud Ahsan
- [Custom Facebook multiple friendselector](http://labs.nascom.be/custom-facebook-multiple-friendselector) from Naslab